# Correct test for categorical response variable and multiple binary independent variables and a phylogenetic relationship

Tags: regression, logistic, phylogeny

I have a dataset of ~2000 phylogenetically linked strains. These strains encode 2 binary traits and were isolated from 3 different environments (A,B,C).
I want to test if encoding the traits makes strains more likely to exist in a certain environment, and if the two traits interact (environment ~ trait1*trait2),
but I am unsure how to this properly.

Is this a problem that is best approached used regression? I have tried binPGLMM with multiple compairsons of my environments A vs B, B vs C etc. I am unsure how to correctly test a categorical response variable with binary interacting traits, and a phylogenetic relationship.

Comment: Hi James, not sure if this is a problem that needs to incorporate phylogenetic relationship, given that the response variable is the environment (multinomial), not the traits of the strains. I can't see how the three environments would cause phylogenetic autocorrelation in the residuals. Anyway, the R package `MCMCglmm` family= "categorical" could be what you're looking for https://coggle.it/diagram/WhbkkxE2BAAB0R0m/t/summary-of-phylogenetic-comparative-methods-diogo-b-provete

Comment: Thanks for the link, A very useful graph. I was including he phylogeny as the traits are heavily correlated by the phylogeny? Is that incorrect thinking?

Comment: I believe so. Try to diagnose the residuals and test if there's any kind of autocorrelation left